# How to deactivate snapshot?

Tags: android, android-studio, snapshot

How i can unchecked/disabled Snapshot in Android Studio 3.0?

In `Android Virtual Device Manager` missing field - `Snapshot`.
Earlier such option was when you try to edit your `Virtual Device`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think such settings exist for the time being. But I find this to be a viable alternative: You can force AVD to cold boot everytime it gets launched (as oppossed to "quick boot"-ing it) like so:

1. Open your AVD Manager.
2. Select your AVD of choice, and edit its settings.
3. Tap on the Show Advanced Settings button.
4. Under the "Emulated Performance" sub-category, "Boot option" menu, check "Cold boot".

[Link to the screenshot I've prepared. Haven't got enough rep to embed images just yet. Bummer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk14v.png)

Comment: Perhaps you also know the difference between `quick boot` and `cold boot`?

Comment: Upon reading more into it, it appears that `quick boot` is a term for booting up the AVD from a previous snapshot. Meanwhile `cold boot` is booting up the AVD from scratch.